# ros2 node does not launch from a python launch file

Tags: ros2, node

The `detector_cmd` node does not run when the first two actions added. But the `detector_cmd` node runs correctly if I remove the first two actions. Below is my launch file:

```
import os
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    # Set the path to different files and folders.
    pkg_share = FindPackageShare(package="br2_tf2_detector").find("br2_tf2_detector")
    br2_tiago_dir = FindPackageShare(package="br2_tiago").find("br2_tiago")
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, "rviz/urdf_config.rviz")

    # Launch configuration variables specific to simulation
    use_rviz = LaunchConfiguration("use_rviz")
    rviz_config_file = LaunchConfiguration("rviz_config_file")

    declare_rviz_config_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="rviz_config_file",
        default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
        description="Full path to the RVIZ config file to use",
    )

    declare_use_rviz_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        name="use_rviz", default_value="True", description="Whether to start RVIZ"
    )

    start_br2_tiago_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(br2_tiago_dir, "launch", "sim.launch.py")
        ),
        launch_arguments={"world": "empty"}.items(),
    )

    detector_cmd = Node(
        package="br2_tf2_detector",
        executable="detector_improved_node.py",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[{"use_sim_time": True}],
        remappings=[
            ("input_scan", "/scan_raw"),
        ],
    )

    # Launch RViz
    start_rviz_cmd = Node(
        condition=IfCondition(use_rviz),
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="screen",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    )

    # Create the launch description and populate
    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Declare the launch options
    ld.add_action(declare_rviz_config_file_cmd)
    ld.add_action(declare_use_rviz_cmd)

    # add any actions

    ld.add_action(start_br2_tiago_cmd)
    ld.add_action(start_rviz_cmd)
    ld.add_action(detector_cmd)

    return ld
```

Comment: It would be best if you've also added the cmd output showing the error the launch file throws. Without it its just a guessing game.

Comment: Please also clarify your question into something that can have a clear answer. Just posting that something didn't work is unlikely to get a useful answer.